# Scheduling an event inside plugin class is not working

Tags: php, plugin-development, wp-cron

`wp_schedule_single_event` is not firing.
I wrote a function that is posting to external API, if it failed I schedule the same posting function to run 5 seconds later in cases of timeouts.
Here's the simplified code of the function:

```
class MyPlugin {
    public function post( $fields, $type ) {
        // Posting to external API logic, if it failed I schedule the same function to run in 5 seconds.
        wp_schedule_single_event( time() + 5, 'post', array( $fields, $type ) );
        
        return;
    }
}
```

I assumed that the `post` function is simply not found so when the time comes for that function to run, nothing happens, so I tried to use:
`wp_schedule_single_event( time() + 5, MyPlugin->post(), array( $fields, $type ) );`
OR
`wp_schedule_single_event( time() + 5, 'MyPlugin->post', array( $fields, $type ) );`

Nothing seems to work! How can I get the same function to run with the same accepted args, 5 seconds after it failed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I assumed that the post function is simply not found so when the time
> comes for that function to run, nothing happens

The second parameter for [`wp_schedule_single_event()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_schedule_single_event/) is actually an event name, which is really a hook. So the event/hook could be named `my_event`, `my_plugin_retry_post`, etc., and if you want the `post()` method to be called via that hook or when that event runs, then you need to attach the method to that event.

Something like so, assuming that your class is instantiated on page load:

```php
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: My Plugin
Version: 1.0
*/

class MyPlugin {
    public function __construct() {
        // Calls the post() method when the my_event hook runs.
        add_action( 'my_event', array( $this, 'post' ), 10, 2 );
    }

    public function post( $fields, $type ) {
        // your API call logic

        if ( the API succeeded ) {
            // your code here
        } elseif ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'my_event', array( $fields, $type ) ) ) {
            // The last 2 parameters are the same as the 1st & 2nd for wp_next_scheduled().
            wp_schedule_single_event( time() + 5, 'my_event', array( $fields, $type ) );
        }
    }
}

// Instantiate MyPlugin on page load.
// Or immediately when WordPress loads this plugin.
global $myplugin;
$myplugin = new MyPlugin;

/* Then later on, e.g. in a function, you could do:
global $myplugin;
$myplugin->post( [ 'foo', 'bar' ], 'baz' );
*/
```

Or if you want, you could instead create a callback which calls the `post()` method and attach the callback to your event.

Comment: I've been breaking my head on this for days, thank you very much for the help with this Sally! Much appreciated! :-)

Comment: Glad it helped  but sorry for the typo - `new My_Plugin` - which I've just corrected 

Comment: That's alright hehe, I was looking at the logic, I'm using a loader function so that action is actually loaded in a different way than what you wrote. You helped me realize that I need to create a custom action that fires the `post` method in my class. :-)